# How to create bitmap indexes in Django

Tags: django, django-models

What is the canonical way of creating [`bitmap indexes`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/data_acc.htm#i23051) in Django?

Customized migration using [`RunSQL`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#runsql) opeartion? How to maintain the indexes afterwards also raw queries?

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # Dependencies to other migrations
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(
          sql="CREATE BITMAP INDEX name  ON table (column);"
          reverse_sql = ...
      ),
    ]
```